# When open new rgl devices, the plot style is very different from the default one

Tags: r, plot, rgl

When I use rgl package plot several 3d graphics in different canvas(rgl device) after using rgl.open() and set the bg as white, the plotting style seems so different from the default one. Is there a way to set this? Please see pics show below. When rotate those two graphs, very different experience you can get. You can try plot same graph in default canvas, open a new one and plot the same pic.

[image: default plot canvas][image: added canvas]

Besides, is there a way to change the outter box of the coordinate from a cube to a sphere?

Comment: I think this is going to be a bit hard to debug & reproduce.  Can you at least tell us the results of `sessionInfo()`, and maybe a little more detail about your OS?

Comment: R version 2.14.2 (2012-02-29)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.92.894

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.2                Thanks

Comment: Not sure we understand the sphere bit. Do you want an opaque sphere? How do you want it labelled? Polar coordinates? lat-long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(**edit**) Use `open3d()` instead of `rgl.open()` to open the new window. The documentation warns against mixing `rgl.*` calls with `*3d` calls, and I guess this is an example.  Here are three plots -- default, `rgl.open()`, and `open3d()` ...

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(1:4,1:4,1:4)
rgl.open()
plot3d(1:4,1:4,1:4)
open3d()
plot3d(1:4,1:4,1:4)
```

And the results side-by-side:

[image]

Session info:

```
R Under development (unstable) (2012-12-14 r61321)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
[locale snipped]
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.92.894
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to maintain the same setup from session to session I think you would need to open package 'rgl' at startup (see `?Startup`) and specify the `rgl.materials` setting that you wanted to use. I have searched for options settings in the Index from help(package=rgl) and failed to find an options setting. There is a list object in the workspace named `r3dDefaults` which could be modified. Perhaps:

```
r3dDefaults$bg$color <- "white"   # Change the value to get something different
# > names(r3dDefaults)
# [1] "userMatrix" "mouseMode"  "FOV"        "bg"         "family"     "material"
```

The differences between device behavior between the `*.r3d` commands and the `rgl.*` commands are laid out in `?r3d` and to a less complete extent in `?open.3d` .

Regarding the desire for a spherical coordinate reference see the `help(rgl.bg)` page and try out the 'sphere=TRUE' argument. (I didn't find it that pleasing but YMMV.)

```
rgl.open()
rgl.bg(sphere=TRUE, color=c("grey","blue"), lit=FALSE, back="lines" )
```

Comment: not quite working here. I tried simply with plot3d(1:4,1:4,1:4), the background is sphere, but inner side cube still exists. And what I mean by sphere coordinate means I can zoom in an out as well. I can view the whole sphere if I zoom out. I cannot show you a picture right now but I'm sure there are many examples out there. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would help if you did actually find us an example and link to it, as I can't quite follow your description.  In fact, I would recommend that you edit your question to delete that bit and post a new question (StackOverflow posts are supposed to contain just a single question ...)

Comment: @lolibility: You are mixing the rgl.* and *3d functions. You have been advised by BenBolker and the help pages you should have read NOT to do that. They have different coordinate systems.